# Kotlin function with nullable/nonnull input mapped to nullable/nonnull output

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to figure out a way to combine these two functions into one,

```
fun parse(string: String): LibObject {
  return SomeJavaLibrary.parse(string)
}

fun parseNullable(string: String?): LibObject? {
    if (string != null) {
        return parse(string)
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the input is nullable I want the output to be nullable, otherwise it's nonnullable. Almost like parameterized nullability. I'm guessing it's not possible but figured I'd ask. If not, is there a  more elegant alternative?

Answer (score 6):

> If not, is there a more elegant alternative?

[Single expression functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions), [`?.` safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) and standard library functionial inbuilts like [`.let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) are all your friends, and while cannot parametize functions as you wish, can bring down your code to just two lines:

```
fun parse(string: String): LibObject = SomeJavaLibrary.parse(string)
fun parseNullable(string: String?): LibObject? = string?.let { parse(it) }
```

---

**EDIT**: You may be able to take advantage of generic type parameters and the fact that nullable types are a supertype of their non-nullable counterparts, but I am not experienced enough to solve this across multiple types.